# Combining different coordinate tables/maps into one table

Tags: mapinfo

I am working on a project which has now seen a change in the geographical boundaries, polygons, eg regions, whereas I have particular customer long/lat data relating to the old boundaries. How do I build a table that shows what old region the customer fell into and what region the customer now falls into?

Second linked to the above the old regions may fall into 1 or more of the new region, who to I build a table that shows the old region and what region or regions it may fall into and also show this on a map?

Answer (score 1):

Spatial Join or Intersect
I recommend customer point and boundary polygon and performing intersect Geo Processing operation

Answer (score 1):

You have *table1* and *table2*. You can ask the simple query in MapBasic or SQL Select:

```
Select * from table1, table2 where table1.Obj intersects table2.Obj into Selection
```

The result in *selection*/*Query3* will be all the intersections between the objects in *table1* and the objects in *table2*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks KDawg, apologies for my delay. Much appreciated, I had done that previously and I wasn't coming back with your answer, it did any and it, so I must have been doing something wrong and you gave a bit more, so thanks.

Comment: @Jase , my answer didn't work for you? If you'd like more help let me know!